# Android: Portrait mode on devices that are wider than long?

Tags: android, android-screen-support

Some devices as I understand are defined in a different matter where they are wider than long.
Meaning they have hardware buttons on the long side of the phone.

So what is portrait mode on these devices? Same as on normal devices? So I won't run in to problems here if my app supports only portrait mode?

Comment: I believe that supporting only portrait mode is a mistake. It will crash on devices that have landscape slide out keyboards, it will crash on Google TVs, and it will look weird on most tablets. Please do everyone a favor and do the little bit extra of work required to make your app work in landscape mode, or ensure that those devices can not install your application (otherwise, you'll get negative reviews).

Comment: I don't support tablets. Google TV=xlarge screen? Dont support that. landscape slide keyboards, dont know.